# Embed youtube video from HTML5 Video tag

Tags: html, video

Need some support regarding the HTML% Video tag and play youtube video on the page itself.

Any idea how to accomplish this, I've followed different answers, but no luck yet.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
       <iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Pranjan,

My mistake, since I couldn't mention in the question. But that has to be without iframe.